# CakePHP developer tries out JavaScript MV*. Gets confused

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

I have a few years' background with server-side MVC app development using CakePHP and a few more with vanilla PHP. Sadly I can't say the same about JS apps, although I do have experience in spicing up static pages with Mootools.

So now I'm trying to study client-side app building and my success so far hasn't been so great. Since the only MVC I've touched is CakePHP, every JS MV* framework seem incomprehensible at best. It doesn't help at all that I've grown so accustomed to writing neat CakePHP and Mootools Class code that big blocks of JS code feel just disorderly.

I've even tried to write my own simple MVC-like lib by imitating CakePHP for mostly academic use. I guess it's needless to say that I haven't really gotten anywhere with it.

Some things I realised while studying and writing my own MVC:

- Js is asynchronous. CakePHP works the way it does because PHP is synchronous. In JS there's an endless list of things that need to be implemented differently and about just as long list of things that can be done differently thanks to async. What are the most important differences between server-side MVC(or CakePHP implementation of it) and client-side MV*?
- I still don't quite get the concept of client-side models. In Cake they handle data validation and database connections. Client on the other hand is an unsafe environment, so client-side models can only do basic data filtering, pre-validation and default values. Am I completely wrong here?
- Some apps require a server counterpart. Should Server also be MVC?
- It seems that in client-side MV* you can have multiple controllers simultaneously. Although I kind of understand that it has its uses, my knowledge at this point is so little I can't even think of a better question than "What good does it do?"

I've also downloaded [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) and tried to examine the different frameworks with little success. The main problems with it are that it's only single-page(actions happen at different urls but the layout stays the same) and the implementations are so different that I'm having hard time even comprehending the basics, let alone finding the best suited framework for me. Also, it doesn't communicate with the server in any way, which is a huge disappointment since I'd wanted to see how different frameworks do that.

So, the optimal answer to this question would be a link to a book called **Client-side JavaScript MV* For Dummies (Who only have experience in server-side MVC)**, which would earn you somewhere around 500 internets in addition to the regular StackOverflow rewards.

I would be extremely thankful for any insight(ful links) on any of my ramblingly written question's topics. You will be rewarded with the standard +1s and as a further incentive I promise to write your nickname on a post-it note and keep it on my monitor for the next month. The person with the most helpful answer of course gets an *Accepted* and additionally may provide a picture to be printed along their nickname to be attached to my monitor.

Comment: I'm continuing my own MVC project. I figured out most parts of how client-side MVC works, though the Model layer is still kind of fuzzy for me since direct db queries to the server are out of the question. In other words Client Models act so differently from Server Models that I'm having hard time deciding how wide the implementation should be and what example to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to know where you ended up on this one. PHP was my first love, and while I still enjoy the ease of the language, it's hard to really take it seriously when it so clearly is being phased out for faster, more scalable technologies.

You hit it on the head that javascript's asynchronousness complicates things, but it definitely opens the doors for performance increases. There are quite a few libraries (more for node.js than client side work) that aim to make javascript written as if it's synchronous - again I don't see it helping with your current ask, but it's good to know other's share your pain.

I think MVC in javascript can be thought of like this:

M: the models are simply an explanation of your data. So if you have a person, you can say that every person has a first name that's a string, an age that's an int and so on. Now whenever you create a new person, you can have validation. Models, client side, tend to be very simple, I've found.

V: views are another interesting thing. Some like to have a big set of render functions that contain strings of HTML (ew). Other's like to have the views just be a wrapper for a templating engine like handlebars.js (probably a better solution).

C: functions pretty much identically to a controller in PHP.

My advice for you would be to NOT write you own, but rather take Backbone.js (quicky becoming the industry standard), learn it inside and out, and perhaps build on top of it.

Good luck!

Comment: I actually tried out some js MV* frameworks. Sadly I couldn't relate with any of them. I think it was a great decision to start my own MVC-like framework. It was a wonderful learning experience and I almost instantly gained some valuable insights which I wouldn't have learned that quickly while playing with other frameworks. My goal was to mimic CakePHP as closely as possible, which went otherwise great but I kind of hit a wall with organizing Model, ModelView and Controller layers. Right now the project is on a break but I'm planning on returning to it as soon as I have more time.

Comment: If it makes it's way to github, let me know!

Comment: Sure. There's still a lot to do, so I wouldn't get my hopes up :)